# Manipulating excel with C#.net

Tags: .net, excel, c#-4.0

I want to ask which is best library to manipulate excel sheets from C# . Things i would be doing with excel sheet will be sorting the sheet , using formula =EXACT() , Inserting few columns by using shift down cells option . Copy data from Database to excel.

I want to know which library would provide more independence to play with excel

Thankyou

Comment: Or i consider using csv file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com) a try. It handles sorting, inserts, deletes, plus a ton more. Here's the [Sorting Data](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sorting%20Data&referringTitle=Documentation) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`?  I believe that exposes all of the functionality you get from using VBA (`ActiveSheet`, `Cells`, `Range`, etc..)